# Unable to read Query Parameters Using GetPage - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router

I'm using `GetMaterialApp.router` from getx as I have used it to handle navigation in my app, but surprisingly it does not provide the same set of parameters as `MaterialApp.router`.

Nevertheless, I added routes using `getPages`. I have been trying to access `Query` parameters but it does not work. I'm able to access `Path` parameters using `Get.parameters` but it does not work for `Query` params.

Here's my code, and I intent to take `test1` as query parameter, and I'm getting `null`;

```
 GetPage(
          name: '/:session/:test',
          page: () {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(title: Text('${Get.parameters['session']}')),
              body: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('${Get.parameters['test']}'),
                  Text('${Get.parameters['test1']}'),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
```

I'm trying to open the app using a dynamic link and for path params it works fine but it does not seem to work for query params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started off by using `GetMaterialApp.router` as I had previously used `MaterialApp.router` to handle `query` parameters, when user taps on a link to open the app. This way I was able to read `path` parameters, but was getting `null`, when trying to access `query` parameters.

After failing to find any solution, I decided to shift back to `GetMaterialApp` and see if it offers routing options just like the `GetMaterialApp.router` constructor, and with that my problem was solved.

```
GetMaterialApp(
        initialRoute: '/',
        getPages: [
          GetPage(
            name: '/',
            page: () {
              return const OdooAuthWrapper();
            },
          ),
          GetPage(
              name: '/signup',
              page: () {
                return  AddNewPasswordPage(token: Get.parameters['token'],);
              }),
        ],
        // home:  getPage(),
      ),
```

`GetMaterialApp.router` has more complex routing configurations to offer, and for some it might make more sense to use it, but in my case `GetMaterialApp` was enough.

Answer (score 0):

According to the creator of Getx, `Get.parameters` and `Get.arguments` are ephermal and have to be assigned to a variable. [Reference](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/1608#issuecomment-875882424)

> **Read from query**

```
//Path  /:session/:test?param1=value1&param2=value2

final queryParams = Get.parameters;
final param1 = queryParams['param1'];
final param2 = queryParams['param2'];
```

> **Read from path**

```
//Path /session/param1/param2

 final param1 = Get.parameters['param1'];
 final param2 = Get.parameters['param2'];
```

Comment: As you can see in the code I have posted, this is exactly what I have done, but I getting `null` when I try to access `query` parameter.

Comment: I found the solution, and I had to switch back to `GetMaterialApp` from `GetMaterialApp.router`.